# How to get all validation Errors from SAX-Parser?

Tags: java, xml, validation, groovy, saxparser

i would like to get all validation Errors from the SAX-Parser, but with my snippet i only receive the first. How can i achieve this?

Thank you!

**Snippet**

```
def factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)
def xml = new StreamSource(inputStream)
def xsd = new StreamSource(new FileReader(schema), systemId)

try {
    factory?.newSchema(xsd)?.newValidator()?.validate(xml)
} catch(SAXParseException saxpe) {
    continueImport = false
    log.error("Error while parsing the import xml", saxpe)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried implementing an [ErrorHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.html) ? This will let you receive and record errors/warnings and fatal errors.

From the doc:

> If a SAX application needs to
> implement customized error handling,
> it must implement this interface and
> then register an instance with the XML
> reader using the setErrorHandler
> method. The parser will then report
> all errors and warnings through this
> interface.

Here is a [code example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler).

Comment: Hi @Brian, links are broken! Is there a chance you can fix them? Thanks you in advance!

Comment: @CodeSlave - now amended. Thx